# WPF - System.InvalidOperationException on ContextMenu.IsOpen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, contextmenu

I was given the following exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'ContextMenu.IsOpen'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.
```

I guess the exception is quite self-explanatory, however I have no idea on how to fix it.

Here is my code:

### XAML

```
<Button
    x:Name="btnNotifications"
    Height="50px"
    Width="auto"
    Padding="15 0"
    Click="btnNotifications_Click"
    ToolTip="Notifications &amp; Agenda"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
    BorderThickness="0">

    <Button.Style>

        <Style TargetType="Button">

            <Style.Triggers>

                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">

                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"/>

                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">

                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>

                </Trigger>

                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">

                    <EventTrigger.Actions>

                        <BeginStoryboard>

                            <Storyboard>

                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContextMenu.IsOpen">

                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>

                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                            </Storyboard>

                        </BeginStoryboard>

                    </EventTrigger.Actions>

                </EventTrigger>

            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>

    </Button.Style>

    <Button.Content>

        <StackPanel
            Orientation="Horizontal">

            <Image
                Source="/Resources/Icons/Notifications.ico"
                Width="25px"
                Height="25px"/>

            <Label
                x:Name="lblNotifications"
                FontFamily="Century Gothic"
                FontSize="25px"
                Foreground="Maroon"
                Visibility="Collapsed"/>

        </StackPanel>

    </Button.Content>

    <Button.ContextMenu>

        <ContextMenu
            x:Name="btnNotificationsMenu">

            <MenuItem 
                x:Name="btnNotificationsNoNew"
                Header="No New Notifications."/>

            <MenuItem 
                x:Name="btnNotificationsSeperator"
                Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"
                Height="2px"
                Focusable="False"
                IsHitTestVisible="False"/>

            <MenuItem 
                x:Name="btnNotificationsNoAgenda"
                Header="Your Agenda is Empty."/>

        </ContextMenu>

    </Button.ContextMenu>

</Button>
```

### Code Behind

```
public static void NewAppointmentForm()
{
    MainWindow appointment = new MainWindow(new AppointmentForm(true));
    appointment.btnNotificationsMenu.IsOpen = false;
    appointment.ShowDialog();
}
```

Obviously wrapping the above code in a `try catch` and calling `Close()` on `appointment` fixes the issue. However, it is more of a workaround than a clean solution.

This issue occurs whenever I try to close the window through another Button. I tried closing the window using `Close()` method within an `EventHandler` and also as a command through XAML - `Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"`.

I would be really grateful if someone could shed some light upon this issue.

May I point out that the `Button` containing the `ContextMenu` is wrapped inside a `Border` which is placed directly in the `MainWindow`.

[image: Exception & Details]

If more detail is needed, please do ask. Thanks :)

Comment: I think I found the issue, inadvertently I clicked on another button, which had no command or event handler. This caused the application to crash. I added a `ContextMenu` to this `Button` and voilà, it closed without crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a typical Isaac silly mistake.

Basically, I copied the `Button` which had the `ContextMenu` and pasted the code to create two `ContextMenu`-less buttons. Having the following applied to the `ContextMenu`-less buttons caused the program to crash:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">

    <EventTrigger.Actions>

        <BeginStoryboard>

            <Storyboard>

                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContextMenu.IsOpen">

                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>

                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

            </Storyboard>

        </BeginStoryboard>

    </EventTrigger.Actions>

</EventTrigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding the property with parenthesis:

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContextMenu.IsOpen)"
```

See [PropertyPath XAML Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms742451%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The XAML parser doesn't know how to resolve the property because it can be attached to any DependencyObject.